# $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right) $ Does this sum converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right) $$
>   Does this sum converge or diverge?

I tried this:

$$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)  =  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{-1}{2n-1}\right)  +  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) $$ and I know that $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)$ diverges. But what about $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{-1}{2n-1}\right)$ ?

I know that if $ \sum a_n $ converges and $ \sum b_n $ diverges then $ \sum \left(a_n+b_n\right) $ diverges.

Comment: Hint: for small angles, $\sin x$ is asymptotic to $x$.

Comment: $\sin{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+O(n^{-3})$.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show that $\sin(1/n)$ is a decreasing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108363/how-to-show-that-sin1-n-is-a-decreasing-function)

Comment: Note that:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{(-1)^n}n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{-1}{2n-1}\right)+\sin\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\ne\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{-1}{2n-1}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac1{2n}\right)$$

Comment: Have you tried the alternating series test?

Answer (score 5):

Hint. Note that
$$\sin\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)=(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
and the sequence$\{\sin(1/n)\}_{n\geq 1}$ is positive and decreasing. Then apply [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

P.S. About the odd subsequence: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{-1}{2n-1}\right)=-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)=-\infty$.

Comment: thank you very much!